# Typeで示される型を要素に持つ配列を作り、値をまとめてセットするには？

Tags: c#

デシリアライザのようなものを作るにあたり、文字列から指定した型に変換してプロパティに設定する、というのは `TypeConverter` と `PropertyDescriptor` で実現できました。それで次は型付けされたコレクションに対応しようと考えています。

最初に考えたのは次のようなコードでした。

```
string[] input = new [] { "1", "2", "3" };
PropertyDescriptor prop = /* int[] なプロパティを指している */ ;
var converted = input.Select(prop.Converter.ConvertFrom).ToArray();
prop.SetValue(converted);
```

しかしこれでは `object[]` になってしまい、 `int[]` のプロパティに代入することができません。このような配列を作るにはどうするとよいでしょうか？

`Activator.CreateInstance()` のようにコンパイル時には `object` で要素を受け取り、`Type` で指定した型の配列を作るメソッドがないものかと思ったのですが、ないようで。。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問を書いて間もないですが、 `Array` 型の存在に気づきました。要素の値を指定して初期化こそできないものの、`Type` からの生成、`object` 型での代入ができるようです。

```
string[] input = new [] { "1", "2", "3" };
PropertyDescriptor prop = /* int[] なプロパティを指している */ ;

Array converted = Array.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType.GetElementType();
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; ++i) {
    converted.SetValue(prop.Converter.ConvertFrom(input[i]), i);
}

prop.SetValue(converted);
```

あるいは変換結果を `object[]` にしておけば、`Array.Copy()` を使うこともできます。

```
string[] input = new [] { "1", "2", "3" };
PropertyDescriptor prop = /* int[] なプロパティを指している */ ;

object[] converted = input.Select(prop.Converter.ConvertFrom).ToArray();
Array typedarr = Array.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType.GetElementType();
Array.Copy(converted, typedarr, converted.Length);

prop.SetValue(typedarr);
```

さらには `Array.ConvertAll()` というメソッドで変換しながら別の配列に・・・と思ったのですが、これはジェネリクスを使っているため今回は使えませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

[Expression.NewArrayInitメソッド](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.newarrayinit(v=vs.110).aspx)を使って`Expression`を組み立てるというのは回答としてありでしょうか？
これでしたら第１引数は`Type`です。

Comment: 数が分かっていれば `new T[]{ x[0], x[1], x[2] }` といったExpressionを使いまわせそうですが、要素数が実行時までわからない場合は毎回Expressionを組み立てることになるのでしょうか…？

Comment: 要素数が不定なのであれば、`IEnumerable<Expression>`を受けるオーバーロードはどうでしょうか？

Comment: ああえっと、`Expression.NewArrayInit` を呼び出す時点で各要素を表すExpressionが決まっていないといけないので、要素数が変わったらまた`Expression.NewArrayInit`の実行から `.Compile()` までやり直さないといけない、という話です。これはそのオーバーロードでも変わらないですよね。